# "IEnumerable <string>" does not contain a definition for "Split"

Tags: c#, .net

First, my code is separated by quotes, then by commas:

```
string source = "\"kk\"jlu,fhhfh,hrhrh,rhrhr";

List<string> data = new List<string>();

var parts = source.Split('\"');
data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 != 0));
data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0).Split(','));

var result = string.Join(" | ", data.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
Console.WriteLine(result);

Console.ReadKey();
```

on line:

```
data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0).Split(',')); error:<br>
```

**"IEnumerable " does not contain a definition for "Split", and it was not possible to find an accessible extension method "Split" that takes the type "IEnumerable " as the first argument**

What to do to make it work?

Comment: You need to create a string from the result of the `Where`, using `new string(parts.Where(...)` is an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) so you can't use it on multiple strings.

I guess you want to use `SelectMany` with `Split`:

```
data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0).SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was occurring because you were trying to add array of array of strings.

```
    string source = "\"kk\"jlu,fhhfh,hrhrh,rhrhr";

    List<string> data = new List<string>();

    var parts = source.Split('\"');
    data.AddRange(parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 != 0));
    parts.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => data.AddRange(x.Split(',')));

    var result = string.Join(" | ", data.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```